# Changing column names of multiple raster bricks using names() in R?

Tags: r, raster, names

knowing Internet,

The data I want to work with is divided into ~60 raster tiles of 10kx10k pixels. I've managed to get through the entire process for a couple of testing tiles and am currently busy trying to tune the scripts workflow for a large amount of files. 
Just background information thats only partially related to the question: My project goal is to classify UAV aerial imagery using RF and SVM algorithms.

I used the following code to load a list of my tiles as rasterBricks into R.

```
dir <- "C:/Users/mypath/"
rastlist <- list.files(path = dir, pattern='.jp2', 
                       all.files=TRUE, full.names=FALSE)
allrasters <- lapply(paste0(dir, rastlist), brick)
```

Each rasterBrick has 4 spectral bands as columns that I want to rename accordingly (B1-B4). 
Using the names function, I'm able to individually change the column names for one brick out of my list.

```
names(allrasters[[1]]) <- paste0("B", c(1:4))`
```

Since I've never worked with larger amounts of data before. Is it easily possible to repeat the renaming process for every raster in the allrasters list? Generally, how do I use functions on every single list object? I'm am still trying to get the hang of R, so excuse me if the question seems out of touch.

EDIT: I realized I could probably just set up for-loops for every step that is supposed to include all raster bricks in my list, including the renaming. Is there a more elegant/less processing-intensive approach?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow; it might help if you included a sample of your data: try  `dput(head(allrasters)`

Comment: Thanks a lot! I've solved the problem using the setNames function within lapply. 

`new_col_name <- paste0("B", c(1:4)) 
allrastsrenamed <- lapply(allrasters, setNames, nm = new_col_name)`

`dput(head)`

worked fine for me too!